# Do Test Runner and Testing Framework exists separately in Java?

Tags: java, test-automation-framework, testng, junit, testing-framework

As per my knowledge, test runner is any software that takes testing code and as per the configuration, executes the code and collate the results while the testing framework is basically the name given to specific pattern of writing code which is efficient and readable

1. Please correct defintions if incorrect.
2. There are few testing frameworks in Java (like JUnit, TestNG, Cucumber, Serenity etc) which are test runner + testing framework. Please let me know if I am incorrect.
3. If I am incorrect in the previous point, please let me know example test runners (which is not a testing framework) and testing frameworks (which is not a test runner) in Java

Answer (score 1):

Normally what you call a Test Runner is a part of testing framework that is responsible to define which code of yours can be considered a test code and that is responsible to execute the test code. Test runner does not make sense with no respect to test framework as well as vise versa.